# What is the locus of vertices of isosceles triangles with a given base?

Tags: geometry

I can think of a perpendicular line to its base. But I am confused when the two sides are placed onto the base, then it is not a triangle anymore? Am I wrong?

Comment: That is the degenerate case. And it does not matter if you ask me. The locus is a straight line perpendicular to the base.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Your locus will be the line perpendicular to the base and cutting it in half **minus** the midpoint of the base.